# Accessing servletContext from a service within an integration test

Tags: grails, service, integration-testing, servlets

I am trying to access the `servletContext` (application context) from a service into an integration test.

Here is how I try to allow it into my integration test:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH 

class ScraperServiceIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {
   ScraperService scraperService

    def testStoring() {
        scraperService = new ScraperService()
        scraperService.servletContext = new SCH() 
        scraperService.storing()
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is how I use the servlet context in my service:

```
class ScraperService {

    static transactional = true
    def servletContext 

    synchronized def storing() {
        servletContext.numberOfCreditProvider = "whatever"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
No such property: numberOfCreditProvider for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assigning your `servletContext` in your test to the `ServletContextHolder` instead of the actual context itself.

You probably want this in your test:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH

def testStoring() {
    scraperService = new ScraperService()
    scraperService.servletContext = SCH.servletContext
    scraperService.storing()
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()
```